# How to make sense of the raw data CSV from the Garmin VIRB 360 Camera?

Tags: export-to-csv, data-processing, garmin

I flew Garmin VIRB 360 Camera on a High Altitude Baloon (HAB). I used the FitCSVTool to convert the  .fit file from the camera data to a csv file. But that just gave me bunch of random variables and numbers scattered in the file with titles like Field 5, Field 6...

How do I use this data to get a file with data arranged properly time stamp wise (speed, lat, lon, etc)?

Link to the complete raw data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eB5jBQIhM65OSedJwlaXVxmp8okupPAM/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=110252714149488450277&rtpof=true&sd=true

I think the data is divided in a cells as per time stamps.